# Remember user sign up

Tags: python, flask

I am having trouble with the signup/login process. I am using Flask as Backend

Here's the setup:

When a user visits the site they see a signup page, all this data is stored in a sqlite3 db. After they press create account they get redirected to the dashboard. The next time they visit the site they are supposed to go to the Login page instead of the signup page.

But how do I manage that?

I am using Login_Manager

This is my signup/login code part

```
def index():
return redirect('signup', code=302)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            return 'invalid user'


    #return form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data

return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
form = RegisterForm()
hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
if form.validate_on_submit():
    new_user = User(username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return render_template('dashboard.html')


   # return form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data

return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with flask but maybe you could use a cookie to remember that this user already signed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, cookies are the way to go. Here's a simple implementation in Flask:

Add these additional import statements:

```
from flask import request, make_response
```

Change `def index()` to check if the user has a cookie with a username:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    username = request.cookies.get('username')
    if username:
        return redirect('login', code=302)
    return redirect('signup', code=302)
```

When they register, create a cookie for them:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()
    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
```

Here are the new lines. We save the response object so we can add a cookie to it and then return it.

```
        resp = make_response(render_template('dashboard.html'))
        resp.set_cookie('username', form.username.data)
        return resp
```

This is documented in [quickstart under cookies](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#cookies).

Comment: While it is not directly related to the question, if anyone is trying to reproduce/run @Wouter Lefebvre's code, Wouter is probably using: flask_wtf, wtforms, flask_login, werkzeug.security and flask_sqlalchemy. You'd need to import things from all of them to get the code to work and config a database.